# WooCommerce Product Attribute Error

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to run this script for adding a **product attribute**. This script has two stages. If i run the whole script, the **phase1** executes fine but the error is thrown from **phase2**. The interesting thing is that if i run the whole script again, both phases works as i expected.

Is there any reason why the terms are not being added in the first attempt?

> ```
>   //PHASE 1
> ```

```
global $wpdb;


$sql="SELECT count(*)  FROM ".$wpdb->prefix ."woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies where attribute_name='mycbgenie-star-rating'" ;
$result = absint($wpdb->get_var( $sql ));


if($result==0) {    
        $insert = $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies',
        array(
            'attribute_label'   => 'CB Rating',
            'attribute_name'    => 'mycbgenie-star-rating',
            'attribute_type'    => 'select',
            'attribute_orderby' => 'order_by',
            'attribute_public'  => 1
        ),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d' )
    );

    if ( is_wp_error( $insert ) ) {
        throw new WC_API_Exception( 'woocommerce_api_cannot_create_product_attribute', $insert->get_error_message(), 400 );
    }

    // Clear transients
    delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );

} //end of result==0
```

> //PHASE 2
>   //***************************

```
$result=wp_insert_term(
      ' 5 Star ', // the term 
      'pa_mycbgenie-star-rating', 
      array(
        'description'=> '5 star rating',
        'slug' => 'mycbgenie-5-star-rating',
        'parent'=> 0
      )
    );
    if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
                echo $result->get_error_message();
    }
```